# Merge Data with MQT with zero impact on performance

Tags: java, db2, websphere

I have a project fetching data from DB2 database and we have a following scenario over which I need quality inputs. Thanks in advance.

1. Current Application is fetching data from table A (Let’s say SALES) table from DB Schema say ORIGIN_X.
2. The same table with different name exists in other schema say ORIGIN_Y.
   Both tables has more 5 million records in each and growing.

   **Problem Statement**
3. I want to merge the data from both the schema/tables to present combined view on UI without compromising performance.
   The number of records are not more than 200 to show on UI but scanning 5 + 5 =10 million records degrades the performance.

**Solutions worked so far.**

1. Created logical view and tried to fetch the date from it but the query performance is dead slow.
2. Thinking of MQT (so as can create index on column) in DB2 equivalent to Materialized view and still progressing.

**Help Need**

1. Are these both approaches right for the problem statement? If yes, what should be done better to proceed with MQT?
2. What is the better approach other than above two?

**Thoughts?**

Comment: Unless you know how to see and examine and compare access-plans, the advice can only be general. Also do you know how to use the index advisor for whatever Db2-platform you are using (Z/OS, i-series, Linux/Unix/Windows - you should always specify the platform because the advice can depend on that)? . The overhead of maintaining an MQT cannot be known unless you know the costs of alternatives.  Merging two tables of 5 million rows each is not a big deal with a good access plan.

Comment: A `UNION ALL` view should be fine. Not that you can't use `UNION` (or `UNION ALL`) in anything other than a `MAINTAINED BY USER` MQT. Post your DDL and more details if you need more help.   E.g. what does the query that selects the 200 rows look like?